# Google takeout doesn't include shared photo albums

Tags: google-drive, google-photos

Google takeout is a great way of backing up all of your google data, but many of the photos I am interested in are in shared albums created by others, which don't seem to come through in Google takeout.

Does anyone know how to backup all of google photos (including shared albums)?

Comment: The idea of Takeout is that you take out __your__ data, not "everything you can access".

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @pnuts I have 'shown' the shared albums in my albums, but I don't believe there is a way to copy it. Is there?

Comment: @Michelle Good point. I was hoping someone knew of a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear you can.  But you can go to your shared album at photos.gooogle.com and select 'download all' from the dot menu.  This will allow you to backup that shared album.